# How can I disable the Live Reload Widget on Vaadin 14.10.0?

Tags: vaadin-flow

I have a Spring Boot application that I run with the Spring Developer Tools disabled (`spring.devtools.restart.enabled=false` in my application.properties) for running my automated Selenium tests against it. However, the Vaadin Live Reload Widget still appears and obscures UI elements, which I need to access in my Selenium tests.

I have tried to put `vaadin.devmode.devTools.enabled=false` in my application.properties and also to run my application with `-Dvaadin.devmode.devTools.enabled=false`, but to no avail. So how can I get rid of this widget entirely, short of running Vaadin in production mode?

FWIW, this is the error message I get in my UI test, which seems to confirm that the widget is in the way:

`Element <vaadin-button class="save-button" theme="primary" tabindex="0" role="button">...</vaadin-button> is not clickable at point (1857, 953). Other element would receive the click: <vaadin-devmode-gizmo url="./vaadinServlet/" backend="SPRING_BOOT_DEVTOOLS" springbootlivereloadport="35729"></vaadin-devmode-gizmo>`

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is typically to run the server in production mode. Then you are testing what your users are using and you do not have any extra tools. As a bonus, it might be faster as the JS bundle is compiled once on server startup and not separately for each browser instance used in the tests

If you do want to run in development mode to run tests locally, then a good solution can be to inject a CSS snippet in the test that hides the dev tools, like `vaadin-dev-tools {display:none;}`. This could be done either from the test itself or e.g. using a query parameter to the application. If you do it this way, you do not have to restart the server between development and running tests.

The parameter is supposed to work also but I cannot see any effect when using it. There is also an issue about removing the disabling parameter as some development mode functionality relies on the dev tools window being there: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/16329

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good solution for local development, which is why I precluded production mode in my question. Of course we are running Vaadin in production mode on the CI server, but this question was meant to be specifically about how to disable the Live Reload Widget in development.

Comment: Yes it would be sufficient to hide the widget via CSS. The name of the widget is `vaadin-devmode-gizmo`. However, I haven't found a way to load CSS only in development mode.

Comment: I have tried to disable the vaadin dev-server entirely by excluding it in my build.gradle:

`implementation.exclude group: 'com.vaadin', module: 'vaadin-dev-server'`

But this did not disable it. Perhaps I specified the wrong package.

Comment: And another point: it seems to be NOT enough to run the server in production mode (by passing the parameter vaadin.productionMode=true), it must actually be built with this flag enabled. If I just pass the flag to my bootRun command, then the application is not loaded at all. Therefore we still have no way to develop Vaadin without using the Dev Tools Window.